# How can I accomplish this sine-like function?

Tags: javascript, math, graph

In order to accomplish a smooth alternating animation, I would like to use a sine-like function in javascript, which should look like one of the red graphs.

The blue graph represents a regular sine-function:

```
var blueY = Math.sin(x);
```

[image: raw graph]

In the end, I would like to modify the graph to look similar to the following blue graph:

```
// scaled and translated sine-graph
var blueY = (1 - Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 2)) / 2;
```

[image: final graph]

How can I accomplish one of the **red graphs**? I do only need a one-liner that returns the y-value when given an x-value. The graph shouldn't have corners to achieve a smooth animation.

Additional info: the absolute value should be lower than from a sine-function at most points (except near the extreme points), to result in a sharper animation.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpqt383w/)

Comment: Please add some info about what type of input you wish to graph.  Is it a 1-dimensional array of x values, or something else?

Comment: I only need the formula for such a red graph, which, given an x-value, returns the y-value (it should look like my code)

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "sine-like". The red looks hand-drawn. Do you want it to actually look like that or to follow an actual sine curve? Do you just want it to cap it between 0 and 7?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It should look roughly like the hand-drawn graph, but it should repeat indefinitely

Comment: it depends on how the red graph is defined. but only the sine function would produce a perfectly smooth animation because its derivative is again a sine function.

Comment: I added a fiddle. It's really important for me, that the speed of the object is more constant in the center of movement, and that it leaves the ending points faster

Comment: Does adding another sine wave at double the frequency and a reduced amplitude give the effect you desire? Something like `var blueY = (1 - (Math.sin(2 *x * Math.PI / 2) / 10 + (Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 2)) / 2;` (Probably the frequency multiplier and amplitude need to be adjusted).

Comment: you are missing parentheses in your formula ;) but I assume it is not what I desire, but just my bad drawing which you misunderstood. The function should still be a wave, but I wonder how to alter a sine-function

Comment: It sounds like all you need is something like a piece-wise function. Linear between the top and bottom and behaves as a sine between the edges. You can implement it as an actual piece-wise function. That would be one way. The other way is to ditch the formula and just move your object with easing manually.

Comment: Well, if it's not possible I might end up creating a piece-wise function as you told. Unfortunately, css easings are not and option and calculating bezier curves in js might not be the most efficient approach either

Comment: You could use `y = -Math.sign(x) * Math.sign( Math.abs(x)%4-2)*(1-Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.abs(x)%2-1), 1.5) )`. Instead of 1.5 you can also insert any other value (values <= 1 will result in corners). (period: 4, range: [-1; 1])

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for :) I will accept your answer when you post it (I don't need it to work in negative range btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following function: `y = 0.5*Math.sign(x) * Math.sign( Math.abs(x)%4-2)*(1-Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.abs(x)%2-1), 1.5) )+0.5` (instead of 1.5, other values are also possible)

Comparison with the sine function (in blue):

[image]

Comment: You just saved my day :)

Comment: Could you explain a little more how you came up with that?

Comment: @OmarShehata: I've got a brother who is very good in maths... (Short explanation: a function like x^1.5 always has a tangent with gradient 0 at (0|0) and contains (1|1) - the rest was mirroring and modulo for repetition)